# AS3: Tweener onComplete doesn't work?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to trace a simple tween using Tweener, but the onComplete doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import caurina.transitions.*;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
    Tweener.addTween(block_mc, {rotationY:180, time:1, onComplete:flipInitComplete});
}

function flipInitComplete(e:Event):void {
    trace("hello");
}
```

Comment: Are you adding a new tween every on every frame for a reason?

Comment: I just want the rotation to happen once on enterframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of Tweener as acting independently of the timeline, much like a Timer. You don't need to call Tweener.addTween() every frame. Just call it once and it will run. Right now your Tweener never completes because you keep restarting the Tween every frame.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm over thinking as usual.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
    Tweener.addTween(block_mc, {rotationY:180, time:1, onComplete:flipInitComplete});


function flipInitComplete():void {
    trace("hello");
} // end flipInitComplete

}//end enterFrameHandler
```